# How to transfer data from excel to powerpoint using Perl?

Tags: perl, ole, perl-module

I am using Active Perl from ActiveState and would like to to transfer data from an Excel sheet to a particular table on the slides in a particular Power point file.

How do I do it in Perl?

Comment: Have you searched at http://search.cpan.org/ ?

Comment: it would include read data from excel sheet(column wise), process it and idsplay the same in a perticular slide in ppt.

Comment: if you are on windows, better do it in vba or powershell. Both source and target are MS products

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you call your Perl script from VBA.

You can do that like this(in VBA):

```
ShellWait "c:\perl\bin\perl.exe c:\path\to\script.pl", vbNormalFocus
```

Also try the [`Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242087%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) API that VBA provides.

**UPDATE**

I suggest you write to disk first(in Excel). And then you read from disk(in Powerpoint). And you do this using VBA, both of these. Using Perl for this makes little sense because you're going to get wrapped up into file parsing problems and all sorts of other stuff.

Comment: i am looking for the perl code to transfer the data from excel to a specific slide on a ppt....kindly help me with it.

Comment: I suggest you write to disk first(in Excel). And then you read from disk(in Powerpoint). And you do this using VBA, both of these. Using Perl for this makes little sense because you're going to get wrapped up into file parsing problems and all sorts of other stuff.